# jQuery show() for Twitter Bootstrap css class hidden

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I notice that jQuery `show()` or `fadeIn()` doesn't make DOM element marked with class `hidden` appear because the jQuery functions only remove the `display: none` specification. However, the `visibility` is still set to `hidden`.

I wonder what is the best possible way to work around this?

1. Remove the `hidden` class on the element
2. Change the visibility property
3. Overwrite the hidden class in my own css

In particular, I want to know whether fixing this with jQuery or css is better and why.

Comment: I generally don't use {visibility: hidden} because it leaves the element in the DOM to take up space. Is there some reason you need to do so?

Comment: @isherwood The `visibility: hidden` is from bootstrap responsive.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The css class you're looking for is `.collapse`. This sets the element to `display: none;`

So using `$('#myelement').show()` will work properly.

**UPDATE :**
Bootstrap v3.3.6 has updated .collapse back to:

```
.collapse {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It also works with `.slideDown()`, `.fadeIn()`, etc. `.hidden` in Bootstrap is for stuff you never want to be displayed.

Comment: Is it new in bootstrap 3?

Comment: No - I've seen it used in the documentation.
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
This line was taken from v2.3.2 examples.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer no longer works with Boostrap 3. `.collapse` now also sets `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: Works in my Bootstrap 3?

Comment: Mine too @JamesMcCormack

Answer (score 23):

This will fade your invisible element in and remove the class

```
$('#element.hidden').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn().removeClass('hidden');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7qxVL/

If you don't really need the element to be invisible (ie take up the space) tho you might wanna redefine .hidden (in you local css, don't change bootstrap source, or even better, in your local LESS file).

Comment: Thanks worked for me! I simplified to just do ::  fadeIn().removeClass('hidden') - no need to manipulate css directly or hide.

Comment: See the answer posted by @IrishJoker. You shouldn't be using `.hidden` for elements you want to display using javascript. Use `.collapse` instead.

Answer (score 15):

Warning:

bootstrap 3.3.0 just changed .collapse to:

```
.collapse {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Which is a breaking change for jQuery.show()  I had to revert back to inlining:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none;" >
</div>
```

to continue using jQuery as follows:

```
$('.alert').html("Change a few things up and try submitting again.").show()
```

The only class I could find in bootstrap 3.3.0 to apply just 'display:none' is

```
.navbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I can't see a good reason for Bootstrap to do this. I personally always have another css file, used for 'overriding' css settings - I'd replace the .collapse to just have the display setting. This way, you can go forward without worrying about everything breaking. Pain in the message :(

Comment: The solution in Bootstrap 3.3.x is to use `.collapse('hide')` and `.collapse('show')` instead of jQuery's methods.  You can set the initial visibility directly in the HTML via the class `collapse` (to hide) or `collapse in` (to show).  See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse.

Comment: The latest version 3.3.6 has reverted this change

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I used this patch:

```
$(function() {
  $('.hidden').hide().removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Then I had another problem, since my application generates new elements and append/prepend them. What I finally did is after genereting the new element I do:

```
var newEl = ...;
$(newEl).find('.hidden').hide().removeClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 5):

For me it was because bootstrap is using the `!important` hack for both class hide and hidden.

So you can't use the `show()` etc methods provided with jquery. Instead you have to overwrite even more horrible code overwriting the hacky code.

```
$('#myelement').attr('style', 'display: block !important');
```

!important is a last resort option and really shouldn't be used in a core library like bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

This works, but I'm going to try the first answer and change the classes to `.collapse`.

```
.toggleClass('hidden')
```